# Insert Data into room database after retrofit success, coroutine problem

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using Retrofit to get news record from API server, if it success then it will write data to room database as code below using insertAll, but  this code generate an error as follow
**Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time**

I tried to use Coroutine, withContext(Dispatchers.IO) but I think it's not correct, thank you for any help

```
suspend fun refreshNews(queryString: String="", page: Int = 1) {
  withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    RetrofitClient.instance.getAllNews(buatObjectNewsQuery(queryString), page)
        .enqueue(object : Callback<NewsGetAllResponse> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<NewsGetAllResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Timber.tag(TAG).i("sorry network error")
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<NewsGetAllResponse>,
                response: Response<NewsGetAllResponse>
            ) {
                val newslist = response.body()?.asDatabaseModel()
                if (newslist != null) {
                    database.databaseNewsDao.insertAll(*newslist)
                    Timber.tag(TAG).i("dalam refresh jumlah data ${newslist.size}")
                }
            }


        })

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code should look more like this. Isolating the callback code with `suspendCoroutine` so that stuff like `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` works as you expect.

```kotlin
suspend fun refreshNews(queryString: String="", page: Int = 1) {
    val call = RetrofitClient.instance.getAllNews(buatObjectNewsQuery(queryString), page)
    val response = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<NewsGetAllResponse> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<NewsGetAllResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                cont.resumeWithException(t)
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<NewsGetAllResponse>,
                response: Response<NewsGetAllResponse>
            ) {
                const.resume(response)
            }
        })
    }

    val newslist = response.body()?.asDatabaseModel()
    if (newslist != null) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            database.databaseNewsDao.insertAll(*newslist)
            Timber.tag(TAG).i("dalam refresh jumlah data ${newslist.size}")
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Ideally you want to make an extension function for that, so it doesn't look so intimidating to read.

```
suspend fun <T> Call<T>.awaitResponse(): Response<T> {
    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
        continuation.invokeOnCancellation {
            cancel()
        }
        enqueue(object : Callback<T> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: Response<T>) {
                continuation.resume(response)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>, t: Throwable) {
                continuation.resumeWithException(t)
            }
        })
    }
}

suspend fun refreshNews(queryString: String="", page: Int = 1) {
    val call = RetrofitClient.instance.getAllNews(buatObjectNewsQuery(queryString), page)
    val response = call.awaitResponse()

    val newslist = response.body()?.asDatabaseModel()
    if (newslist != null) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            database.databaseNewsDao.insertAll(*newslist)
            Timber.tag(TAG).i("dalam refresh jumlah data ${newslist.size}")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke setValue on a background thread.Iam getting this exception

Comment: There's no `setValue` in the code. You're probably using `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` and calling `setValue` in it.

Comment: Yeah i need to get the size of the list from db., for that i am using the livedata value.size

Comment: I think you should ask a new question, there's not a lot of info for me to go off of.

Comment: @DominicFischer hi, I need to do almost the same but using java. can you please look at my question? I have everything set up I just don't where to do the insert(): if onResponse or somewhere else: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68602466/how-to-fetch-data-from-api-and-insert-the-data-to-the-database-in-android-studio