# how to fetch data from api and insert the data to ROOM (database) in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, json, api

My code is working fine but every time people open the coin activity it takes about 5 seconds to load 500 coins from coinmarketcap api (name, symbolName, price, vol and marketcap). I used a `facebook shimmer` to let people know that something is loading but 5 seconds is a lot tho because the app is loading more heavy stuff within 1 to 2 seconds, for example, wordpress data with images. But, these 500 coins in 5 seconds is not cool... Here is my code...

```
    public void getCoinList() {
    
    //posts = 500
    ApiInterface apiInterfaceCoin5 = 
    APIClientCoin.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("limit", posts+"");

     Call<CryptoList> call5 = apiInterfaceCoin5.doGetUserListAll(params);
  
    call5.enqueue(new Callback<CryptoList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CryptoList> call, Response<CryptoList> response) 
    {

            shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
            shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            swipeRefreshLayout5.setRefreshing(false);

            int beforeCoinSize = cryptoList5.size();

            CryptoList list5 = response.body();


            cryptoList5.addAll(list5.getData());

            recyclerView4.setAdapter(adapterCoin5);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CryptoList> call, Throwable t) {
            //Toast.makeText(CryptoListAllCoinActivity.this, "onFailure", 
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          //  Log.d("XXXX", t.getLocalizedMessage());
            call.cancel();
            progressBar3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            swipeRefreshLayout5.setRefreshing(false);
        }
      });
   }



@Headers("X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY: HIDDEN")
@GET("/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest")
Call<CryptoList> doGetUserListAll(@QueryMap Map<String, String> params);
```

Adapter:

```
    // Involves populating data into the item through holder
    // binds the data to the TextView in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int 
    position) {
    // Get the data model based on position
    Datum datum = mData.get(position);

    //load coin icon
    //if the link doesn't work then you have to upload it into 
    your own server
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(new 



     StringBuilder
     ("https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/")

    .append(datum.getId())
    .append(".png").toString())
.placeholder(R.drawable.money_icon).into(holder.coin_icon);
    
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(new 


  StringBuilder
    ("https://s3.coinmarketcap.com/generated/
    sparklines/web/7d/usd/")
                    .append(datum.getId())
                    .append(".png").toString())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.line_24)
            .into(holder.sparkline);


    TextView symbolName = holder.symbolName;
    symbolName.setText(datum.getSymbol());

    // Set item views based on your views and data model
    TextView name = holder.name;
    name.setText(datum.getName());

    TextView price = holder.price;
    TextView priceDetails = holder.priceDetails;

    TextView marketCap = holder.marketCap;
    marketCap.setText("$" + 
   formatNumber(datum.getQuote().getUSD().getMarketCap()));


    ImageView coin_icon = holder.coin_icon;
    ImageView sparkline = holder.sparkline;


    if(datum.getQuote().getUSD().getPrice() >= 1) {
        price.setText("$" + 
 formatNumber(datum.getQuote().getUSD().getPrice()));
    }else{
        price.setText("$" + String.format("%f", 
  datum.getQuote().getUSD().getPrice()));
    }

    TextView textView24h = holder.textView24h;
    textView24h.setText(String.format("%.2f", 
   datum.getQuote().getUSD().getPercentChange24h()) + "%");


    if(datum.getQuote().getUSD().getPercentChange24h() <0.000).{
        //red
        textView24h.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#EA3943"));
        arrowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down);
        sparkline.setColorFilter(Color.RED, 
   PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        sparkline.setImageResource(R.drawable.btc_spike);

        //changeImageColor(context, sparkline,000);

    }else{
        //green
        textView24h.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#18C784"));
        arrowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up);
        sparkline.setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, 
 PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        sparkline.setImageResource(R.drawable.btc_spike);

    }


}

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(new 
     StringBuilder
    ("https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/")
                    .append(datum.getId())
                    .append(".png").toString())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.money_icon)
            .into(holder.coin_icon);
```

**UPDATE**

Now I have the database setup but not sure how to insert data into the database...for example:
where do I add this:

```
AppDatabase db = 
AppDatabase.getDbInstance(this.getApplicationContext());

    //coin object


    db.coinDao().insertAllCoins();
```

inside the onResponse? and how?

**UPDATE 8-5-2021:**

**AppDatabase.class**

```
@Database(entities = {Coins.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

public abstract CoinDao coinDao();

private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

public static AppDatabase getDbInstance(Context context){

    if(INSTANCE == null){

        INSTANCE = Room
                .databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), 
 AppDatabase.class,"DB_COIN")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();

    }

    return INSTANCE;
}


}
```

**CoinDao**

```
@Dao
public interface CoinDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM coin_table")
    List<Coins> getAll();

    @Insert
    void insertAllCoins(Coins... coins);

    @Delete
    void delete(Coins coins);

    @Update
    void updateUsers(Coins... coins);
}
```

**Coins.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "coin_table")
public class Coins {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
public int id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "name")
public String name;

@ColumnInfo(name = "symbol")
public String symbol;

@ColumnInfo(name = "slug")
public String slug;

@ColumnInfo(name = "circulating_supply")
public Double circulatingSupply;

@ColumnInfo(name = "total_supply")
public Double totalSupply;

@ColumnInfo(name = "max_supply")
public Double maxSupply;

@ColumnInfo(name = "date_added")
public String dateAdded;

@ColumnInfo(name = "num_market_pairs")
public Integer numMarketPairs;

@ColumnInfo(name = "cmc_rank")
public Integer cmcRank;

@ColumnInfo(name = "coin_symbol")
public String lastName;

@ColumnInfo(name = "last_updated")
public String lastUpdated;

@ColumnInfo(name = "price")
public Double price;

@ColumnInfo(name = "volume_24h")
public Double volume24h;

@ColumnInfo(name = "percent_change_1h")
public Double percentChange1h;

@ColumnInfo(name = "percent_change_24h")
public Double percentChange24h;

@ColumnInfo(name = "percent_change_7d")
public Double percentChange7d;

@ColumnInfo(name = "market_cap")
public Double marketCap;

}
```

**UPDATE 8-6-2021** Base on Muhammad Shuja answer
For the CoinRepository I am getting this error:
[image]

But if I change it to CriptoList then it says it require a List lol.... Any idea why?

Please note I use Coins with the s because that is the class name.

also if I change it to CriptoList it says that this

```
 coinDao.insertAll(response.body());
```

require a List

I have my `public getCoinList()` a lil bit up for reference on how I am currently getting the data from the api.

And, yes I want to update the data every 1...like I would like to make an api call and update the data every 1 minute. Thankssssssssss

Comment: I would suggest adding a timer and logging times when different steps get completed, this way you will be able to narrow down your search area, then maybe update your question with your findings so that we can help you easily

Comment: I work a lot with external APIs, and I usually avoid hitting the API servers directly upon user interaction (unless it is not a get - i.e. post, delete, update, etc). I usually have a bunch of jobs running on the background at different intervals, and store the data somewhere (DB, file, etc) and then make it available thru my own APIs. When you have 500 users logged in at the same time hitting the marketcap servers all the same time, you will quickly realize that it makes more sense to get the data once, store it, and access it as often as you need virtually immediately from your own servers.

Comment: @HanletEscaño Yes I would love to do that can you please provide some code? also, can you tell me how the data will be update in the db? like...it will call the api every x time? or something else. Also, i would like to get 3,000+ coins....so your solution can save me

Comment: @Maduro I can't provide code, but the concept is quite simple. For every job that I have I save the response in my DB exactly the same way I get it (albeit I usually serialize/deserialize from/to JSON into objects and then move them to my DB). Then instead of calling the API every time a user wants this data, I get the data directly from my DB. The frequency at which you update your data is up to you and your needs. I have jobs that need to run anywhere from every 5 seconds, to once per day to once per month, it really depends.

Comment: it sounds awesome! Can you please send at least a tutorial ? I'm  just looking for some keywords to see what you need for that...

Comment: @HanletEscaño you can also send me any code or anything at my email... maduro311@gmail.com Thanks,

Comment: @HanletEscaño hey, so i got the database but how can I insert the data from the api? where do I add this: `AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDbInstance(this.getApplicationContext()); db.coinDao().insertAllCoins();`

Comment: create a `CoinRepository` and implement your logic there. If DB is empty or it is required to refresh data, let your repo query data from API and insert it in DB, and then fetch it from DB whenever needed.

Comment: @MuhammadShuja I updated (added some code) to my question...can you provide some code base on what I've posted so far? Thanks,

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: @HanletEscaño now that i read your comment well...do you mean store the data somewhere in a website but not inside the app? For example, right now I am using room to store the data...but then I started to think that each person who download the app will create its own database? and each person will have to make a call to the API to update the Room database? Or is this Room database not store in each person app? =/ Can you please let me know...Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `CoinRepository` and implement your logic there. If DB is empty or it is required to refresh data, let your repo query data from API and insert it in DB, and then fetch it from DB whenever needed.

Check [this codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view) to practically understand Room.

Create `Coin` entity, it's a good practice to keep entity/model classes name singular, and their respective table names plural.

**Coin.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "coins")
public class Coin {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    public String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "symbol")
    public String symbol;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "slug")
    public String slug;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "circulating_supply")
    public Double circulatingSupply;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "total_supply")
    public Double totalSupply;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "max_supply")
    public Double maxSupply;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "date_added")
    public String dateAdded;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "num_market_pairs")
    public Integer numMarketPairs;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "cmc_rank")
    public Integer cmcRank;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "coin_symbol")
    public String lastName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_updated")
    public String lastUpdated;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "price")
    public Double price;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "volume_24h")
    public Double volume24h;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "percent_change_1h")
    public Double percentChange1h;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "percent_change_24h")
    public Double percentChange24h;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "percent_change_7d")
    public Double percentChange7d;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "market_cap")
    public Double marketCap;
}
```

Create `CoinDao` interface and add your query methods in it, I've added additional methods like get(id) and update(coin), you can use them if needed.

**CoinDao.java**

```
@Dao
public interface CoinDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM coins")
    LiveData<List<Coin>> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM coins WHERE id = :id")
    LiveData<Coin> get(int id);

    @Insert
    void insertAll(List<Coin> coins);

    @Update
    public void update(Coin coin);

    @Query("DELETE FROM coins")
    void deleteAll();
}
```

Create your database class as follows:

**DB.java**

```
@Database(entities = {Coin.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class DB extends RoomDatabase {
    private static final String TAG = "DB";

    // DB INFO
    private static final String databaseName = "coin_database";

    // DAOs
    public abstract CoinDao coinDao();


    // INSTANCE
    private static volatile DB INSTANCE;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4;
    public static final ExecutorService databaseWriteExecutor =
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);

    public static DB getInstance(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (DB.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), DB.class, databaseName)
                            .build();
                    Log.d(TAG, "New instance created...");
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Create `CoinRepository` and add your WebAPI/DB logic in it. Notice, I've moved your API call in getCoins() method, you need to modify it according to your logic. Make sure your call response returns `List<Coin>`, or you'll have to create a `List<Coin>` from `CryptoList` yourself.

**CoinRepository.java**

```
public class CoinRepository {
    private static final String TAG = "Repo/Coin";

    private final CoinDao coinDao;
    private final LiveData<List<Coin>> coins;

    public CoinRepository(Application application) {
        coinDao = DB.getInstance(application).coinDao();
        coins = coinDao.getAll();

        Log.d(TAG, "New instance created...");
    }
    
    /*
        I've added boolean flag to check if data reload from Web API is compulsory.
        You can remove this flag and modify it as per your logic.
        
        DataReadyListener is a callback listener.
        Its onDataReady() method gets fired when data is ready.         
    */
    public void getCoins(boolean reload, DataReadyListener listener) {
        if(reload){
            //Modify this portion as per your logic
            ApiInterface apiInterfaceCoin5 =
                    APIClientCoin.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("limit", posts+"");

            apiInterfaceCoin5.doGetUserListAll(params)
                    .enqueue(new Callback<List<Coin>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<List<Coin>> call, Response<List<Coin>> response) {
                            Future<?> future = DB.databaseWriteExecutor.submit(() -> {
                                coinDao.deleteAll(); //remove this if you want to keep previous data
                                coinDao.insertAll(response.body());

                                Log.d(TAG, "Data inserted in \"coins\" table");
                            });

                            try {
                                future.get();
                                if (future.isDone())
                                    listener.onDataReady(coins);
                            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<List<Coin>> call, Throwable t) {
                            //Handle failure here
                        }
                    });
        }
        else{
            listener.onDataReady(coins);
        }
    }

    public LiveData<Coin> getCoin(int id) {
        return coinDao.get(id);
    }

    public interface DataReadyListener {
        void onDataReady(LiveData<List<Coin>> coins);
    }
}
```

And lastley create `CoinViewModel`. You can completely skip this step and query data directly from `CoinRepository`. But `ViewModel` has its own pros, check [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) for details.

**CoinViewModel.java**

```
public class CoinViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private CoinRepository repository;

    public CoinViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new CoinRepository(application);
    }

    public void getCoins(boolean reload, CoinRepository.DataReadyListener listener) {
        repository.getCoins(reload, listener);
    }

    public LiveData<Coin> getCoin(int id) {
        return repository.getCoin(id);
    }
}
```

Now use `CoinViewModel` in your Activity/Fragment, first initialize it:

**UI (Activity/Fragment)**

```
private CoinViewModel coinViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    coinViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(CoinViewModel.class);
    ....
}
```

And finally use your ViewModel to query data. If you want to reload the data from Web API send first parameter as `true`, if you want to reuse existing data from DB keep flag as `false`:

```
coinViewModel.getCoins(true, new CoinRepository.DataReadyListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataReady(LiveData<List<Coin>> coins) {
            //Add or set data in adapter
            //for setData() you need to create setData() method in adapter
            //which first clears existing data and then adds new data to list and notifies about dataset change.
            coins.observe(this, coinsList -> coinsAdapter.setData(coinsList));
        }
    });
```

Hopefully, it helps.

**Update 07/08/2021**

After discussion with OP, I've updated the `CoinRepository` code. Now, instead of relying on boolean flag, it automatically updates data after 1 minute interval using `RxAndroid`:

```
public class CoinRepository {
    private static final String TAG = "Repo/Coin";

    private final CoinDao coinDao;
    private final LiveData<List<Coin>> coins;

    public CoinRepository(Application application) {
        coinDao = DB.getInstance(application).coinDao();
        coins = coinDao.getAll();

        loadCoinsPeriodically();

        Log.d(TAG, "New instance created...");
    }

    public LiveData<List<Coin>> getCoins() {
        return coins;
    }

    private void loadCoinsPeriodically() {
        Observable.interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        aLong ->
                                RetrofitService.getClient().getLatest(500)
                                        .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                        .subscribe(
                                                cryptoList ->
                                                        DB.databaseWriteExecutor.submit(() -> {
                                                            coinDao.deleteAll();
                                                            coinDao.insertAll(cryptoList.getCoins());

                                                            Log.d(TAG, "Data inserted in \"coins\" table");
                                                        }),
                                                throwable ->
                                                        Log.d(TAG, "API observable error: " + throwable.getMessage())),
                        throwable ->
                                Log.d(TAG, "Periodic observable error: " + throwable.getMessage()));
    }

    public LiveData<Coin> getCoin(int id) {
        return coinDao.get(id);
    }
}
```

I've written an example app for OP's use case, [check this Github repo](https://github.com/MuhammadShuja/TestCoinApp) for complete code.

Comment: Hiiiii ...Thank you so much for this code!! I am having an error but I think i know how to fix it. Here where you added ` //Modify this portion as per your logic` I see you are using `Call<List<Coin>> call, Response<List<Coin>> response` so I think...I need to change this to `Call<CryptoList> call, Response<CryptoList> response` this is what im using to make the call to the API...I will try this one.

Comment: I update the question...base on your code. Again, thank you so much for your help!!!! Please let me know if everything is clear in the `update 8-6-2021` questions

Comment: Please read whole answer again, I've mentioned: "Make sure your call response returns `List<Coin>`, or you'll have to create a `List<Coin>` from `CryptoList` yourself."

Comment: you need to update your call to this: `Call<List<Coin>> doGetUserListAll(YOUR_PARAMS_HERE)`

Comment: Just want to make sure you did write `<List<Coin>>` and not `<List<Coins>>` i thought you got confused with the class name that is Coins with the s lol...I will try again and change your Every `<List<Coins>>` to `<List<Coin>>` Thanks again for your help

Comment: yeah use `Coins` instead of `Coin`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235699/discussion-between-maduro-and-muhammad-shuja).

Comment: The code it works! I for got to ask you..is this database inside each person phone? and so every phone will be making call to the api? or This is stored in my own database (inside android) and then people are getting the data from this database?

Comment: the database is going to be inside every user's phone, and yes every phone will be making calls to API

Answer (score 1):

OkHttp client can make 64 requests in parallel by default. You can play with that value and increase [maxRequests](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-dispatcher/max-requests/) number. Create new OkHttp dispatcher:

```java
Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
dispatcher.setMaxRequests(200);
```

Then, initialize OkHttp client:

```java
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        ...
        .dispatcher(dispatcher)
        .build();
```

Finally, add this OkHttp into Retrofit:

```java
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        ...
        .client(client)
        .build();
```

Comment: Hi, someone suggest to put the data in a database and then get the data from there..because its not a good idea to make so many calls to the api. Can you pelease provide the code? or tutorial or any to lead me there..